# C++ 0xC0000005: Trying to make large vector[180][360]

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having a hard time trying to get my computer to allocate a large amount of memory (well within the 32GB on my machine). I'm in Visual Studio 2015, running the target as x64 on a 64-bit machine, so there should be no memory limitations.

Originally I tried to make `vector<int> my_vector[4][180][360]`, which resulted in a stack overflow.

According to the Visual Studio debugger, memory usage does not go above 70MB, so I'm quite curious how the memory problems are occurring. Memory usage on the computer stays with over 25GB free.

Is there any way to declare an array vector such as `vector<int> my_vector[4][180][360]` without memory problems? So far I can only get as high as `v[180][180]`. Most of my vectors will have very few elements. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you really intend to create a 3 dimensional array of vectors? Each vector takes up significant overhead and can pre-allocate space for reserved, but unused entries. This can be checked with the capacity() class function.

Comment: Well, it was just a try with the vectors. But I'm not sure why creating a bunch of big arrays that are within the size limit results in memory problems.

Comment: This actually creates a 3D array of empty vectors.  For instance, the way you would populate a single entry in the first vector is `my_vector.[0][0][0].push_back(3)` Then you can access it by `my_vector.[0][0][0][0]`  I don't think this is what you intend.

Comment: right, what I want is to have a list each of for 3 parameters. for example, a list for each [x][y][z]

Comment: You should look at `array<array<array<array<int,90000>, 360>, 180>, 4> myarray;`  The data is packed so you won't have the overhead of a vector. About 10gb.

Comment: Might have to break it onto smaller chunks. VS has a limit of 0x7ffffffff bytes for an array.

Comment: I doubt that would work because `SizeOfInitializedData` and `SizeOfUninitializedData` fields in PE/PE+ header are only 4 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running into the 0x7ffffffff limit. But I'm not sure why the function with a bunch of [4][180][360][8000]'s aren't working. Should be golden there, no? Not sure what this "stack" thing is... they're global variables, so they're good to go, right?

Comment: It's doable. You have enough memory. I would suggest something like `vector<int>[4][180][360]`  Then you resize() each element to 90000.  Should work fine. After that you can access each int like so `my_vector[n1][n2][n3][n4]`

Comment: To get better answers, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Carlos J, 4x180x360x8000x4 // sizeof( long ) this is already almost 8GB. Size of all static data is at least limited by the PE format which has 32 bit fields even on x64 platform(there can also be a compiler limitation as well). Your only choice is to use dynamic memory at some point as suggested by doug.

Comment: I'm getting some memory problems with `vector<int> v[4][180][360]`, although vector<int> v[180][180] works? But if I make two of them, I get problems.

Comment: Actually 4*4*180*360*90000 = 93,312,000,000 bytes. You need more memory. With your current size it will make virtual memory and go to disk.  The last approach I suggested does work but it will be very slow due to disk access unless you put a really large pile of memory in there. You might also try using 8 bit ints if things permit. That brings it down by a factor of 4.

Comment: Well, the truth is almost all the vectors will be zero. Most of them will be zero (not sure which ones). But it could go as high as 90,000 for a few of the vectors. In total, I have to assign a 2-3 million elements in total to all those vectors (so that's actually fairly small).

Comment: Then only resize the vectors you have. You might also look at sparse matrixes in Eigen.

Comment: Another possibility is the `std::map` which is intrinsically sparse. Not fast but would be much faster than virtual ram in disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     static std::vector<int> my_vector[4][180][360];
>     for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
>         for (int j=0; j < 180; j++)
>             for (int k=0; k < 36; k++)
>                 my_vector[i][j][k].resize(90000);
>      my_vector[1][2][3][4]=99;
> ```

This works on my machine with 24gb by creating virtual to disk. But it is going to be slow more likely than not.  You might be better off indexing a disk file.

You can also use std::map to create a sparse array
>

> ```
>      static std::map<int,int> my_map[4][180][360];
>      my_map[1][2][3][4]=99;
> ```

Comment: Wow, that works. For some reason, declaring it as `static` doesn't bust my computer.

Comment: Try the map version. It will be much less a memory hog and you won't flush to disk cache and no need to initialize vector sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allocating memory on the *stack*? If so, I believe there is a limit before you get a stack overflow error. For Visual Studio 2015, I think the default stack size is 1MB.

For larger arrays, you need to allocate them on the *heap* using the **new** keyword.

Comment: thank you... I'm really not sure how to allocate a huge array, though. I'm trying to do `int* massive = new int[4][180][360][90000];` which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to allocate a multidimensional array, it can get fairly complex. A two dimensional integer array is allocated dynamically as an array of *pointers*, with each pointer allocated to new array of integers. In a naïve version, you will need a loop to allocate (and eventually deallocate):

```
int **a= new int*[1000];
for (i = 0;  i< 1000; i++) {
   a[i] = new int[1000];
}
```

As you can see, multiple dimensions become even more complex and will eat up additional memory just to store pointers. However, if you know the total number of elements, you can allocate just a single array to store all elements (100000 for my 1000x1000 example) and calculate the position of each element accordingly.

I'll leave the rest for you to figure out...

Comment: Sorry, I meant this to be an edit of my previous answer. The SO app does not like me today. :-(